# Alternatives to all these if-statements in my C++ program

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

In my beginners coding class, I was quested with writing a basic C++ code, for a pizzeria scenario which has the following requirements:

- Based on a budget ask the user if they want additional pizza topping.
- Update the Budget and a Invoice accordingly if opted yes for a certain pizza topping.
- Display the summary of all the pizza toppings chosen
- Display the Invoice and the change left

```
cout << "\nHere is a summary of your order: \n" ;

    if (Olives2 == true){
        cout << "-Olives\n";
    }

    if (Onions2 == true){
        cout << "-Onions\n";
    }

    if (Cheese2 == true){
        cout << "-Cheese\n" ;
    }

    if (Salami2 == true){
        cout << "-Salami\n";
    }

    if (Shrimps2 == true){
        cout << "-Shrimps\n\n";
    }
```

This is the part of the code I need some help on:

One of the specifications of the program is to output a list of the ingredients the user opted yes for.

In order to display this list I just used if statements. The variables seen (e.g Cheese2) are updated through switch statements. Here is one of the switch statements used :

```
 if (Budget >= Shrimps1 ) {
        cout << "Any Shrimp? y/n ";
        cin >> Toppings;

        
        switch (Toppings) {

            case 'y':
            Invoice = Invoice + Shrimps1;
            Budget = 100 - Invoice;
            cout << "Your subtotal is R" << Invoice << ", with a remainder of R" << Budget << endl;
            Shrimps2 = true;
            break;

            case 'n':
            cout << "Your subtotal is R" << Invoice << ", with a remainder of R" << Budget << endl;
            break;
        }

    }
```

Thus when user inputs char 'y' the bool Shrimps2 variable updates to true

Is there any way I can avoid using all these if statements and just use loops to make the code cleaner?

Comment: why is there `Shrimps1` and `Shrimps2` ?

Comment: Shrimp1 refers to the price of the specific topping and Shrimp2 is used a variable to show if the user opted for it

Comment: If your code works and has no problem, and you're seeking for improvements, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the suitable place for that, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349513/are-code-improvement-questions-allowed for more information

Comment: Did you not by chace miss the session about using arrays?! Or this is a research question for next session?!

Comment: You could make use of a container that would hold only the chosen elements, then you just have to iterate over it, only the chosen elements will be there, no `if` required.

Comment: Not yet at the chapter for arrays. Is this not possible with loops?

Comment: Some side remarks. (1) Don't use magic numbers. What is 100? (2) Avoid cryptic variable names like Shrimps1 and Shrimps2. Use something descriptive like ShrimpsPrice and ShrimpsOrdered.

Comment: 1. Do not have separate variable for each item. 2. Organize your information in some structures: `struct PizzaTopping { std:::string name; unsigned basePrice; /* cents */, ....  };`. 3. Store menu information in some collection/container: `using PizzaToppings = std::vector<PizzaTopping>;`  4. Store order information in similar container. When you will have containers you will have a loo and only one statement to handle all elements in container (selecting item from menu to order or printing summary of order).

Answer (score 1):

Define function:

```
void fn1( bool b, const char * text )
{
    if ( b == true )
    {
        cout << "-" << text << "\n";
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
cout << "\nHere is a summary of your order: \n" ;

fn1( Olives2, "Olives" );
fn1( Onions2, "Onions" );
fn1( Cheese2, "Cheese" );
fn1( Salami2, "Salami" );
fn1( Shrimps2, "Shrimps" );
```

Array of structures and loop is another method but for 5 items it is not shorter.

PS: Think about array of flags and array of names. Hardcoded items are bad idea. If you get Coca Cola tomorrow what will do - update the program and re-compile?

Answer (score 0):

Like usual this is mostly the matter of selecting correct data structure to represent your intention. There are many ways to solve your task, here I can suggest the use of `std::map` for keeping the information about available toppings, and `std::set` for requesting user input.

```
std::map<int, Topping> availableToppings;
availableToppings[1] = {"olives", 2.5};
availableToppings[2] = {"cheese", 3.5};
availableToppings[3] = {"salami", 2.0};
```

or if your choices ids are consecutive numbers, you can just use `std::vector` and assume user input is the vector idx (starting from 0)

```
std::vector<Topping> availableToppings
{
  {"olives", 2.5},
  {"cheese", 3.5},
  {"salami", 2.0}
};
```

Then you can use have some function to ask the user if they want to select something:

```
int askForTopping(std::ostream& out, std::istream& in, std::map<int, Topping> available)
{
    for (const auto& [key, val] : available)
    {
        // add some welcome message like "press [number] to select optional ..."
        out << key << ": " << val.name << ", price: " << val.price << "\n";
    }
    int choice{0};
    // some input validation? e.g. check if the selected topping exists in the map, decide what to do with special case when user doesn't want to select anything
    in >> choice;
    return choice;
}
```

And then you can ask for the user choice like that:

```
std::istringstream inbuf("2 3");
// standard output for print, stringstream for simulating user reply"
int choice = askForTopping(std::cout, inbuf, availableToppings);
selectedToppings.insert(choice);
for (auto id : selectedToppings)
{
    std::cout << "user selected: " << availableToppings.at(id).name;
}
```

You should implement some input validation, use your functions inside the loop with some reasonable stop condition (e.g. user doesn't want anymore toppings) etc. If you want to allow multiple choices of the same ingredient, use `std::multiset`.

Comment: `std::vector` might relace a `std::map` when the keys are consecutive integers...

Comment: Good point, added sample